# find elements of an array in another array, why do I have this error?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, void-pointers, function-definition

I was trying to visualize the algorithm of this exercise, but I'm having a lot of problems.

the exercise asks to implement this function:

```
extern const void *memmem(const void *haystack, size_t hsize, const void *needle, size_t nsize);
```

- haystack and needle are two pointers to two different areas of memory. haystack points to a memory of size hsize, and needle points to a memory of size nsize.
- find *needle elements in *haystack, and if *needle elements are in *haystack too, return a pointer to the new allocated memory (containing *needle elements) and this pointer has to point to the 0-th element of the new memory.

I hope I've explained it better than the original exercise (it's not clear, so I had a hard time trying to understand it).

---

I've tried to sketch the algorithm this way:

> algorithm accepts two pointers and their sizes. (loop) increment
> *needle by one at each step in order to find a common element (comparing that element with the current element of haystack), and if
> that condition is true, increment a counter by one. Doing this way
> I've obtained the length of the final array. Then, I allocate enough
> memory, and do another loop to copy each element in the final vector.
> last but not least, return this pointer.

this is how is it suppose to look like in code (I know it's not complete, but I'm currently building it step by step, it's not easy at all):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
const void* memmem(const void* haystack, size_t hsize, const void* needle, size_t nsize) {
    if ((hsize == 0) || (nsize = 0)) {
        return NULL; // here, I should've done a NULL pointer exception check too, because haystack and needle may be null pointer too. for now, ignore that. 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
        if (needle[i] == haystack[i])
    } 

}


int main(void) {

    int haystack[] = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    size_t hsize = 6; 
    int needle[] = {-1, 8, 4, 2};
    size_t nsize = 4; 

    int* ptr = memmem(haystack, hsize, needle, nsize); 


    return 0; 
}
```

the crucial part is here:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
            if (needle[i] == haystack[i])
        }
```

because I have this error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type. What does it mean? I've never heard of this error message before. arrays are complete, I've defined them correctly, therefore I don't know why I have that.

Comment: You can't dereferene generic pointers (`void *`). You *must* cast them to their actual type before dereferencing.

Comment: *arrays are complete, I've defined them correctly* No, you have not. There are no arrays involved in that loop at all. You are dealing with pointers inside this function. You cannot have an array of `void` type as it does not have any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type void is incomplete type. Its size is unknown. The compiler has no   possibility to determine the size of objects of that type (though for backward compatibility some compilers have their own extensions that determine sizeof( void ) equal to 1. But this does not satisfy the C Standard).

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 19 The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
> object type that cannot be completed.

So you may not dereference a pointer of the type cv void *. You need to cast the pointer to a pointer to a complete object type to access a pointed object.

In any case this for loop

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
    if (needle[i] == haystack[i])
}
```

even if the pointers were casted is incorrect because `nsize` and `hsize` can be unequal.

I think you need two nested for loops.

Also at least the qualifier `const` in the return type of the function

```
extern const void *memmem(const void *haystack, size_t hsize, const void *needle, size_t nsize);
```

does not make a great sense. It should be removed.

Comment: "if (((int*)needle[i] == (int*)haystack[i])" I've tried to cast this way, but it doesn't work, where do I have to cast?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini At least you need to write if ( ( (  int * )needle )[i] == ( ( int * )haystack )[i] )

Comment: what do you mean by: "nsize and hsize can be unequal"?. It's possible to have hsize > nsize, because the exercise asks to find needle in haystack, needle can be a subset of haystack

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Do a check in your code: `if (nsize > hsize) { /* Handle error... */ }`.

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini In your assignment there is written "haystack and needle are two pointers to two different areas of memory. haystack points to a memory of size hsize, and needle points to a memory of size nsize." Different areas can have different sizes.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow _"even if the pointers were casted is incorrect because nsize and hsize can be unequal."_ You can cast to `char*` and compare, because `char` is 1 byte.

Comment: @Zakk This does not make a sense because it is unknown what elements the areas contain. How to count elements?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Comparing two areas of memory by comparing bytes.

Comment: @Zakk And if a memory denotes an integer array how will you count the number of elements?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini that loop is wrong because `nsize` and `hsize` are not equal. That means using the same index for both arrays does not make sense. You must search for `needle` starting with different offsets within `haystack`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If you have say a 1KB of memory, and you want to compare that to another 1KB of memory. What you can do is compare all the bytes and stop when two bytes are not equal. I guess you don't need to know how many `int`s are there.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Try changing the values of `array1` and `array2` in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/7ccPTWEsG).

Comment: @Zakk It seems you do not  understand the assignment.. If the pointers point to arrays of the type int then  if three bytes will be equal each other what are you going to do?!